# collapse a vector as comma separated string in julia

Tags: printing, julia

I have 1-d vector of values. I want to convert them into a string with values separated by comma. Is there an easy way in Julia to do this? Something like collapse in `r`

```
{julia}
julia> x = [24,122,63,24,83,56,54,175,11,11,24,51,85,92,74,500,80,127,126,59,111,155,132,202,64,164,1301]
```

---

```
#I want output like this as a string
#24,122,63,24,83,56,54,175,11,11,24,51,85,92,74,500,80,127,126,59,111,155,132,202,64,164,1301,27
```

---

```
#I have tried something like this
[julia> [print(i,",") for i in x]
24,122,63,24,83,56,54,175,11,11,24,51,85,92,74,500,80,127,126,59,111,155,132,202,64,164,1301,27-element Array{Void,1}:
 nothing
 nothing
 nothing
 nothing
 nothing
 nothing
 nothing
 nothing
 nothing
 nothing
 nothing
 nothing
 nothing
 nothing
 nothing
 nothing
 nothing
 nothing
 nothing
 nothing
 nothing
 nothing
 nothing
 nothing
 nothing
 nothing
 nothing
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Print most of the values with an ordinary loop, then print the last item (to eliminate the trailing comma):

```
julia> for i in @view x[1:end-1]
           print(i, ',')
       end; print(x[end])
24,122,63,24,83,56,54,175,11,11,24,51,85,92,74,500,80,127,126,59,111,155,132,202,64,164,1301
```

You can also join each item in the iterable with a comma:

```
julia> print(join(x, ','))
24,122,63,24,83,56,54,175,11,11,24,51,85,92,74,500,80,127,126,59,111,155,132,202,64,164,1301
```

Comment: `join(map(string, x), ',')` is exactly what I wanted. Thanks

Comment: @PoisonAlien - Looks like the `map` isn't necessary, and you can just `join(x, ',')` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Also this, which is simpler: `print(string(x)[2:(end - 1)])`.